# Prove that $| x -x_0| \lt \varepsilon$ if and only if $x$ is in the interval $(x_o -\varepsilon, x_o + \varepsilon)$.

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

Let $x_0$ and $x$ be real numbers and let $\varepsilon$ be a real number with $\varepsilon \gt0$.

Prove that  $| x -x_0| \lt \varepsilon$ if and only if $x$ is in the interval $(x_o -\varepsilon, x_o + \varepsilon)$.

Need help proving this... I know that this is the language for "nearness" of a point.

I feel like this prove can't be that difficult. I know I need to prove it both ways and I am wondering if a proof by contradiction would be the best route to go?

Comment: Hint: $|a|<b\iff -b<a<b$.

Answer (score 2):

***Hint:***

$$ |x - x_{\circ}| \lt \epsilon \iff  x - x_{\circ} \lt \epsilon \;\; \text{and} \;\;-(x - x_{\circ}) \lt \epsilon $$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Recall that $|a-b|=|(a-c)-(b-c)|$. Namely, adding or subtracting a constant from both numbers will not change their distance.

Answer (score 0):

If $x-x_0\geq 0,$ then $x-x_0<\epsilon$ or $x<x_0+\epsilon$ and if $x-x_0<0$ then $-(x-x_0)<\epsilon$ implies $x>x_0-\epsilon,$ by combining we obtain what was to shown.